# I want to print number 1 when click the button 1 but it doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

This is a 1st step of making tictactoe game using Java.

I want to print number 1 when click the button 1. There are 9 buttons but it doesn't work what is the wrong I printed the `e.getsource` method and `B1` button they are not same. Why is this happening?

```
package tictactoe;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener{

JFrame frame1;
JButton B1 = new JButton();
JButton B2 = new JButton();
JButton B3 = new JButton();
JButton B4 = new JButton();
JButton B5 = new JButton();
JButton B6 = new JButton();
JButton B7 = new JButton();
JButton B8 = new JButton();
JButton B9 = new JButton();

public void createGui(){
    frame1 = new JFrame();
    frame1.setTitle("TicTacToe");
    frame1.setSize(600, 600);
    frame1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,0,0));
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

    frame1.add(B1);
    frame1.add(B2);
    frame1.add(B3);
    frame1.add(B4);
    frame1.add(B5);
    frame1.add(B6);
    frame1.add(B7);
    frame1.add(B8);
    frame1.add(B9);

    TicTacToe A1 = new TicTacToe();

    B1.addActionListener(A1);
    B2.addActionListener(A1);
    B3.addActionListener(A1);
    B4.addActionListener(A1);
    B5.addActionListener(A1);
    B6.addActionListener(A1);
    B7.addActionListener(A1);
    B8.addActionListener(A1);
    B9.addActionListener(A1);

   // frame1.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==B1){
        B1.setText("1");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToe T1 = new TicTacToe();
    T1.createGui();
}
}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming converntion. variable names should start with lower case character

Answer (score 2):

The reason for you program does not work is that you create a new TicTacToe that you use as parameter to the `JButton.addActionListener()`. Try using `this` instead and remove `A1`.

```
B2.addActionListener(this);
```

Then it will work.

However I have a suggestion to a different approach than using `JButton.addActionListener()`.

Instead you could use the `JButton` constructor that takes an `Action` as parameter. Implement your own `Action` that extends `AbstractAction` and then set the text in the `actionPerformed()` method you need to implement.
You could let the `Action` take a parameter with the text you want to write when pressed.

```
private class PressedAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final String text;

    public PressedAction(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText(text);
    }
}
```